# Transforming a future in Akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to use Akka Streams to concurrently send requests to a server, and then trying to relate each request to an original context (an `Int` in this example). This is the flow I've put together:

```
val createRequestFlow: Flow[(String, String), (HttpRequest, Int), _] = Flow.fromFunction[(String, String), (HttpRequest, Int)]((mkRequest _).tupled)
val sendRequestFlow: Flow[(HttpRequest, Int), (HttpResponse, Int), _] = Flow[(HttpRequest, Int)].mapAsyncUnordered(32)((sendRequest _).tupled)
val handleResponseFlow: Flow[(HttpResponse, Int), String, _] = Flow[(HttpResponse, Int)].map[String]((getStatusString _).tupled)

val handler =  createRequestFlow via sendRequestFlow via handleResponseFlow
```

Particularly, I'm trying to find the way to return a `Future[(HttpResponse, Int)]`. Currently, I'm doing this

```
def sendRequest(request: HttpRequest, ctx: Int): Future[(HttpResponse, Int)] = {
    Http().singleRequest(request).map(r => (r,ctx))
  }
```

but I understand that the fact that this requires an Executor indicates that there is another (better) way to do it.

Comment: You're on the right path, just make `sendRequest` take an implicit ExecutionContext.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way. Akka uses standard Scala [`Future`s](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html) and they by design require an `ExecutionContext` to perform almost any operation. If you really-really don't want to use another thread for this simple `map`, you can create your own `sameThreadExecutionContext` similar to the one Akka uses inside (see [akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts.sameThreadExecutionContext](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f8b4fb55ca3c4d20a503e99ad774f74a3ee36c11/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Future.scala#L77-L83)) so the `map` will be performed on the same thread that handles main Http response, but don't use it for anything more complicated (see also discussion at [GitHub #19043](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19043)).